# i cant edit collection, no object in collection

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode, collections, object-mode

i bring some Blend.file for kit bashing.

however some of collection doesn't have any mesh or material,

so i cant edit.

what should i do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did u directly open the blend file or append/import it? Can you share the blend file so that the problem can be understood properly?
Generally, a linked collection cant be opened to edit because the mesh isn't actually imported.

Comment: thx! it was problem that brought collection ctrl+c,v.
as u said, when i append collection, it work well!!